# how do I get content written of TinyMCE with Angular4?

Tags: angular, tinymce

I need to store the content written inside the tinyMCE editor on my html page after clicking a submit button, but I have no idea how. I have the **EditorComponent** in my **AppModule** imported.

my **component.html** has the following editor embedded in it:

```html
<editor
   (onSaveContent)="somefunction()"
   [init]="{
     height: 500,
     menubar: false,
     plugins: [
       'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
       'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
       'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount',
       'save'
     ],
     toolbar:
       'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | \
       alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
       bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help | save'      
   }">
</editor>
```

I have a function known as **getcontent() { // }** in my **Component.Ts** file. I don't know exactly what to do at this point as other online topics uses Javascript or PHP specifically (I'm using Angular 4)

essentially, I have a string initialized known as **str** and I need this content inserted here to update my backend database.

on other articles, I see them using the class **tinyMCE** and calling functions on it but I am unable to access it in my Angular application.

however, I am able to run **(onSaveContent)="somefunction()"** when I click save; I just need to get the content of what I wrote to a String variable

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that you mentioned `EditorComponent`, I'm assuming you are using [this package](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-angular). In that case, it's simple; you just use `ngModel` to two-way bind the value of tiny mce's editor with a property in your component:

```html
<editor
   (onSaveContent)="somefunction()"
   [(ngModel)]="html"
   [init]="{
     height: 500,
     menubar: false,
     plugins: [
       'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
       'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
       'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount',
       'save'
     ],
     toolbar:
       'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | \
       alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
       bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help | save'

   }"></editor>
```

And in your component:

```js
// String field to store our HTML
html = '<p>Hi, TinyMCE!</p>';
somefunction() {
  // Do something here.
  console.log(this.html);
}
```

Here's a [working stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tiny-mce-angular-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: worked like a charm! problem is it keep saying "Error: no form element found" How do I stop that?

Comment: Interesting. I was **not** getting that error before and am now. I believe it's a strange thing going on with Stackblitz, because I've run this code locally (and I'm doing something similar on a production site) and haven't run in to that problem. And you can fix it by editing a file a couple times on Stackblitz (edit something to cause a refresh and it should work). Try running that code **not** on Stackblitz and let me know if you run in to any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[(ngModel)]="content"
```